# Extract output file from GDAL Command in Python

Tags: python, gdal

I am using subprocess in a python script to create a gridded tiff from a shapefile.
Earlier in the script I have set different variables relevant to the shapefile and this is why they are called within the `gdal_grid` command.

I have found this to be the quickest way to run the gdal_grid command, as using `Gdal.Grid()` is taking over an hour to create.

```
subprocess.call(f'gdal_grid -a nearest:radius1={cell_size}:radius2={cell_size}:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -txe {txextent} -tye {tyextent} -tr {resolution} -zfield z {shapefile} {output_file}.tif')
```

I'm just wondering is there a way I can extract the `output_file.tif` and set it as a new variable for later use in the script? For reference, the  output_file isn't being saved anywhere yet (as I want to push it up to an s3 bucket but can't figure out how to until I've separated it andd it's contents from the subprocess)

The outputfile_file contents will be opened the likes of rasterio

Comment: What do you mean by "...extract..."? Do you want the filename or do you want to read the file into,  for example, a numpy array?

Comment: I would research something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: sorry I should've said, but I want to be able to read the file into the likes of rasterio

Comment: Have you tried if the result of gdal_grid could be saved into a virtual raster .VRT?

Comment: @user30184 no, how do I go about that?

Comment: Short form  `outputfile.vrt`. Explicit syntax `-of VRT ... outputfile.vrt`.

Comment: @user30184 yes but how will that change me being able to assign the output contents to a new python variable for later use?

Comment: If it worked it would take a second to write the VRT output that is just a short XML file. But I think that it will not work with gdal_grid.  I had a try and received `0...10...20...30...ERROR 1: Writing through VRTSourcedRasterBand is not supported.`

Comment: You are using python's f-string notation so I'm assuming you have set the variables between `{...}`. So you should still have those variables after calling `subprocess`.

Comment: yes I have set the variables between ```{}``` :)

Comment: @PyMapr so you think if I put ```gridded_image = output_file.tif``` it should work?

Comment: yes, that should work to keep track of the `output_file.tif`

Comment: @PyMapr sorry, just to check. When creating the new variable would ```output_file.tif``` work or would it have to be defined as ```{output_file}.tif``` as per the subprocess?